# merge .csv files using awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have 15 .csv file. Each file contains records as bellow:

```
EmailID,SendCount,ReciveCount,SendSize(KB),ReciveSize(KB)
user1@domain.com,0,1,0,29
user2@doman.com,1,0,0,0
user3@domain.com,1,0,0,0
user4@domain.com,0,4,0,294
user5@domain.com,0,2,0,35
```

First column contains email id, second contains mail send count, third contains mail receive count, forth and fifth contains total send and receive size.
All 15 file contains some common ids and some different ids.There respective values could be different.

**My requirement:**
I want to merge all these file into single file and if some email id is common in 2 or more files it should get added only once in output file and values under column SendCount, ReciveConunt,SendSize,ReciveSize should get added and only total should get display in there respective column.

Is it possible using only awk and sed script?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is it completely necessary that only sed and awk have to be used ? Or you can use some bash as well ?

Comment: bash's uniq was the first thing that sprung to my mind too, much as I love sed.

Comment: @SaifAsif
If possible, I want pure awk script.
If it is not possible using only awk, we can use some bash shell script also.

Comment: @JohnBarça Yes exactly. I was thinking to advise making a set implementation with `uniq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk -F, '$1 != "EmailID" {p[$1]+=$2;q[$1]+=$3;r[$1]+=$4;s[$1]+=$5} 
        END{for (i in p) print i, p[i], q[i], r[i], s[i]}' OFS=, input*.csv
```

Comment: Thx, it works. As I am very new at awk could you please explain the script in short.

Comment: This awk uses 4 different associative arrays `p, q, r, s` to hold 4 different counts. Index of all those arrays is email address found in column 1. Read an awk tutorial on using associative arrays.